# Show error message box only if all input fields are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4  textboxes, and I need to make sure that before submitting I have at least one of the textboxes filled.

HTML:

```
<form name="parentForm">
    <input name="pf1" id="pf1" type="text">
    <input name="pf2" id="pf2" type="text">
    <input name="pf3" id="pf3" type="text">
    <button type="button" onClick="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function submit()
{
    if ($.trim($("#pf1").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#pf2").val()) === ""  || $.trim($("#pf3").val()) === "")
    {
        alert ('Fields are empty.');
        return false;
    }
...
}
```

the problem is that it only submit if all fields are filled, in my case what iI want is that if only 1 textbox has data, I can submit the form.

Comment: Replace `||` with `&&` then, so you check that all fields are empty instead of either of them.

Comment: Change `||` to `&&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `||` operator use `&&` operator to check for all inputs.

Instead you can compare the count of empty inputs with the total inputs using `filter`. If they are equal, it mean all input fields are empty.

```js
function submit() {
  const emptyInputs = $('input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().trim() == "";
  });

  if (emptyInputs.length === $('input').length) {
    alert('Fields are empty.');
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="pf1" id="pf1" type="text">
<input name="pf2" id="pf2" type="text">
<input name="pf3" id="pf3" type="text">
<button type="button" onClick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: writing same thing. But you are fast.+1

Comment: thanks for your help, it worked... I am feeling very disappointed in me that I mixed the AND and OR functions...

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop on all inputs and if at least one is different than empty submit:

```
$("input").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ""){
         // submit
    }
})
```

Comment: You might want to add some text to explain your answer. What if there are other input elements on the same page?

Comment: He can use a class selector instead of input. I can't teach him all about JS in one post.

Answer (score 0):

if only one field must be filled with a value change your or to and

```
    function submit()
{
    if ($.trim($("#pf1").val()) === "" && $.trim($("#pf2").val()) === ""  && $.trim($("#pf3").val()) === "")
    {
        alert ('Fields are empty.');
        return false;
    }
...
}
```